# How can I test a scheduled flow?

Tags: corda

I'm using the mocking network for testing a scheduled flow, but I can't track the result given because it  isn't returned as a future like using `node.services.startFlow(...)`  .

I've already tried the approach stated in the heartbeat example:

```
val recordedTxs = node.database.transaction {
  val (recordedTxs, futureTxs) = node.services.validatedTransactions.track()
  futureTxs.notUsed()
  recordedTxs
}
```

I've listed the content inside `recordedTxs`, and the one loaded by the scheduled flow doesn't appear. I've also subscribed to `futureTxs` but there are no updates of the observable.

Are there other ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other aspect of testing scheduled flows is by timing the flow using a parameter to moderate it. The corda node's scheduler will kick off a flow that is (by the contract scheduling logic) expected to be done now or in the past. This gives you two ways to check the flow completion.

1. Setting the flow to be scheduled immediately and then check the
   node's database for new consumed states with attributes you'd expect
   to see.
2. Initiate a flow and move the platform clock (in the test setup) to a
   time where the scheduled flow would have completed and then check
   states.

Samples:

```
// Set up the network as:  
net: MockNetwork = MockNetwork(threadPerNode = true)
// Logic to set up nodes 
...
net.startNodes()

// Additional set up 
... 
val scheduledFlow = SimpleScheduledFlow(parameterForImmediateScheduling)
testNode.services.startFlow(scheduledFlow)
net.waitQuiescent()

node.database.transaction {
    // Check validated transactions ...
    // Checks on the states newly produced by the flow ...
}
```

Alternatively,

```
val scheduledFlow = SimpleScheduledFlow(parameterForLaterScheduling)
testNode.services.startFlow(scheduledFlow)
(node.internals.platformClock as TestClock).setTo(valueDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).plusSeconds(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
net.waitQuiescent()

node.database.transaction {
    // Check validated transactions ...
    // Checks on the states newly produced by the flow ...
}
```

Additional Reference:

- https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2.0/node/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/events/ScheduledFlowTests.kt

Comment: This is a great answer. I forgot about `waitQuiescent` and setting the platform clock manually!

Comment: Is this proposal present in the 3.X version ? I was not able to find it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can test scheduled states as follows:

- Invoke a flow that creates a scheduled activity
- Sleep for long enough for the scheduled activity to have occurred
- Check that the scheduled activity has occurred

For en example, see the flow test in the Heartbeat sample (https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/heartbeat):

```
@Test
fun `heartbeat occurs every second`() {
    val flow = StartHeartbeatFlow()
    a.services.startFlow(flow).resultFuture

    val enoughTimeForFiveScheduledTxs: Long = 5500
    Thread.sleep(enoughTimeForFiveScheduledTxs)

    val recordedTxs = a.database.transaction {
        val (recordedTxs, futureTxs) = a.services.validatedTransactions.track()
        futureTxs.notUsed()
        recordedTxs
    }

    val originalTxPlusFiveScheduledTxs = 6
    assertEquals(originalTxPlusFiveScheduledTxs, recordedTxs.size)
}
```

In this test, we proceed as follows:

- We run `StartHeartbeatFlow`. This flow creates a scheduled state that one second later will create a transaction creating another scheduled state, and so on. This means that running `StartHeartbeatFlow` causes a new transaction to occur every second until the node is shut down
- We wait 5.5 seconds. That's long enough for another five transactions to occur
- We check that there are now six transactions in the vault

When using this approach, you must ensure you initialise the `MockNetwork` with `threadPerNode = true`, otherwise sleeping on the thread will block all network activity.